# Order of function execution in mxunit testcase

Tags: coldfusion, mxunit

I'm using MxUnit as a testing framework for my ColdFusion project. But I'm not sure about, in which order the functions in the testcase is getting executed. I've inserted dummy records in DB for my testing, in `beforeTests()` and deleting those records in `afterTests()`. I'm having following functions in my testcase

```
public void function Read() {
//Block of code
}
public void function Save() {
//Block of code
}
public void function Delete() {
//Block of code
}
```

But at first `Delete()` gets executed, so the `read()` returns "No record Found"(failure message), because the record gets deleted in the delete() itself. So I thought that it is running in alphabetical Order and so I changed the function names accordingly(`Read(),Save(),XDelete()` - since it is in alphabetical order). Again the same thing is happening.

But it works fine, when I renamed the functions as `A_Read(),B_save(),C_Delete()`.

So someone explain about in which order the functions get executed.

Comment: Over and above what Simon and Duncan say, you should probably mock-out the bits of your code that hit the DB anyhow. Unit tests oughtn't need to hit the DB in the first place.

Comment: Also: MXUnit is kinda dead. Are you in the position to switch to TestBox? It's a better experience, and is still (very) actively developed. If you're only starting out with your unit tests; I recommend *not* starting with MXUnit.

Comment: Okay @AdamCameron Thanks for your valuable information, will consider about testbox.

Comment: (oh, and all your MXUnit tests will run on TestBox too!)

Comment: @AdamCameron wow! That sounds good..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't guarantee what order they will run in, assume it's random.

See 
http://blog.adamcameron.me/2013/11/unit-testing-mxunit-and-test-scenario.html

> For a given test run there is no guarantee what order tests are run
>   in, although in reality it's down to how ColdFusion exposes them in a
>   CFC's metadata, I think. Their execution order is certainly not
>   randomised. But one should not assume any test execution order. And,
>   indeed, each test really needs to be completely discrete from other
>   tests in the CFC

You really need to rethink how you're doing your tests, so they are all independent of each other.

However if you really must: http://blog.bittersweetryan.com/2012/01/using-new-orderedtestdecorator-in.html

Answer (score 4):

You're probably better off using setUp and tearDown instead of beforeTests and afterTests. That way fresh dummy records will be inserted into the database before each test is run and the tests will not be dependent upon each other.

Comment: yeah! you are correct, but hope it may cause some delay in execution time, for every tests, it will insert and delete dummy records.

Comment: Another approach would be to create a couple of private helper methods, one for create dummy records and another to delete them, and calling the helper methods from the test cases when required.